# Update Query (String --> Date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, insert

I'm trying to update field (Type of Date) from a string field.

The string field example : 20/10/2015

I am new in sql. I tried this query:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmployeeWithCompCar]
SET [EMER_AttachEndDate] = cast([EMER_info1] as date)
```

I get this message:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Can you help me fix it?

Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `convert()` with a format.  So try this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[EmployeeWithCompCar]
    SET [EMER_AttachEndDate] = convert(date, [EMER_info1], 103);
```

The formats are available in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Note:  In SQL Server 2012+, use `try_convert()` instead of `convert()`.  That way, if a string is in the wrong format, the result is `NULL` instead of an error.

Comment: Thank you. 

But if the string is empty It is updating to 1900-01-01. How to change this to not change it from null?

Comment: Add `where EMER_INFO1 is not null` to the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CONVERT with the format style 103.

```
UPDATE [DBO].[EMPLOYEEWITHCOMPCAR]
    SET [EMER_ATTACHENDDATE] = CONVERT(DATE, [EMER_INFO1], 103)
```

And if you don't blank to be updated to 1900-01-01 you can use NULLIF function to avoid that.

```
UPDATE [DBO].[EMPLOYEEWITHCOMPCAR]
    SET [EMER_ATTACHENDDATE] = CONVERT(DATE, NULLIF([EMER_INFO1], ''), 103)
```

[Date Formats in SQL Server](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2008/11/date-formats-in-sql-server.html)

[NULLIF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)